# openID Connect : skip user consent if scope = openid

Tags: scope, authorization, openid, openid-connect

In OpenId Connect, if the scope (in the authentication request) is only "openid",   could the OpenID Provider skip the consent page ?

Comment: Have you tried with the parameter [`prompt=none`](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on the OpenID Connect implementation of the authorization server. For example there could be claims that are appended to ID token by default which are not requested in the authorization request scope list (ex:- A user identifier). Thus there could be a consent page displayed from OpenID Connect provider even when scope value is limited to `openid`.

Rather than when not to show consent page, specification highlight on the scope value `offline_access` ([reference](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#OfflineAccess)). This scope require `prompt` parameter `consent` in authorization request. Thus requiring consent page to be presented to end user.

Comment: With a scope = "openid", The OpenID Provider returns an IDToken containing only the sub (without identity claims). So, I can skip the consent page...

Comment: yet the sub may consist of PII such as an e-mail address, which then would require consent

Comment: @HansZ. Agree.! But still, it's the preference of the system to decide to obtain or not to enforce consent page. For example, I recently came across this blog - https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/updates-to-end-user-consent-for-3rd . It explains how Google handle Consent page. According to that, Email and Profile are core permissions, thus selecting an account to login is taken as the consent to share them (without the interaction of the consent page.!)